# Can subdomain name contain ".com"

Tags: dns, web, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

Can a subdomain contain ".com" as part of the website address.

For example, the domain is "test-testing.com". Can I also have a subdomain as  "test123.com" such that the full address will be something as shown below:

"www.test123.com.test-testing.com"

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can,

On OVH for example I can do this:

[image]